# Unable to convert json to the dictionary in python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x

Iam trying to convert json object to dictionary in python 3. I have following json value

```
[
  {
    "facebook": {
      "PfaceID": "green",
      "DfaceID": "yellow",
      "Time": "04:03"
     }
  },
  {
    "google": {
      "PgoogleID": "yellow",
      "Dgoogle": "green",
      "Time":"05:09"

    }
  },
  {
    "Yahoo": {
      "PyahoID": "red",
      "DyahooID": "Yellow",
         "Time":"06:09"
    }
  }
]
```

```py
import  json



data = 'D:\updated_Color_Value.json'
data_value={}


try:
    with open(data) as file:
        data_value = json.loads(file)

except IOError as e:
    print(e)


print(type(data_value))

for key in data_value:
    print(data_value[key])
```

IN the out put , the type return as list, not the dictionary. Can anyone help to convert json to the dictionary in python 3?

Appreciated for your help in advance
Thank You

Comment: It is a jsonarray and so it gives a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your input json is actually an array of json, it is natural to give a list value. For the list, you can iterate it and check each value by doing this.

```
for item in data_value:
    for key in item.keys():
        print(key)
        print(item[key])
```

The result is:

```
facebook
{'PfaceID': 'green', 'DfaceID': 'yellow', 'Time': '04:03'}
google
{'PgoogleID': 'yellow', 'Dgoogle': 'green', 'Time': '05:09'}
Yahoo
{'PyahoID': 'red', 'DyahooID': 'Yellow', 'Time': '06:09'}
```

---

You can build your own dict by using my above code.

```
import  json

data = './test.json'
temp = {}

try:
    with open(data) as file:
        temp = json.loads(file.read())

except IOError as e:
    print(e)

data_value = {}

for item in temp:
    for key in item.keys():
        data_value[key] = item[key]

print(data_value)
print(data_value['facebook'])
print(data_value['facebook']['PfaceID'])
```

```
{'facebook': {'PfaceID': 'green', 'DfaceID': 'yellow', 'Time': '04:03'}, 'google': {'PgoogleID': 'yellow', 'Dgoogle': 'green', 'Time': '05:09'}, 'Yahoo': {'PyahoID': 'red', 'DyahooID': 'Yellow', 'Time': '06:09'}}
{'PfaceID': 'green', 'DfaceID': 'yellow', 'Time': '04:03'}
green
```

Comment: Thank you @Lamanus, this way i am getting above result. my intention is to get the value for each object key. For eg: 
```python
facebook{'PfaceID': 'green', 'DfaceID': 'yellow', 'Time': '04:03'}

then iterate each object inside like to get result as 
PfaceID': 'green' 

```
i thought it would work if its in dictionary. 

Let me know please if you have an idea? I tried different way to get the above result, but not getting right answer

Thank You

Comment: I add some code. You have to make your own dict by looping the list object into keys.